# time.h functions do not see the header file

Tags: ios, c, xcode, time

I am using structures and methods listed below and including sys/time.h or time.h do not change anything. What can be the problem?

```
    struct tm theTime;
    strptime((char *)nodeValue, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y", &theTime);
    time_t epochTime = timegm(&theTime);
```

I am using XCode and compile for armv7. (Before, this was working perfectly. I don't know what's changed since before..)

I get the following errors:

```
    Variable has incomplete type 'struct tm'
    Implicit declaration of function 'strptime' is invalid in C99
    Implicit declaration of function 'timegm' is invalid in C99
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have included another header path which also includes time.h and which's content is irrelevant. I fixed it and everything works again.

So, in situations like this, it is a good idea to check header paths to see if there is any other file with the same name but in another directory.

@ouah's answer is great and it is a good tip, however it is not the direct solution of my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Enable the declarations by defining  feature test macro `-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200809L` at compilation time or before including the header:

```
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
 #include <time.h>
```

See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html) for more information on feature test macro `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`.

Comment: @frankish try with `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700` instead.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it and wrote it as answer. However I hit +1 for your answer as it is valuable.